# Anti-vax origins of "vaxxed"

Tags: etymology

The world* is talking about getting vaccinated, and saying "vaxxed" to do so. Here are the first five Google News results for "vaxxed":

- *"Free Joints for Vaxxed People in DC Today"*
- *"Please Go Get Vaxxed So We Can Hang Out Again"*
- *"The New York Post spent weeks fearmongering about vaccines. Now it's telling them to 'GET VAXXED'"*
- *"Get vaxxed and ready"*
- *"Vaxxed, waxed and ready to kick off Shot Girl Summer in L.A.? Here are 5 expert tips"*

That last one hints at my initial curiosity: vaxxed, waxed – isn't it odd we put two *x*s in *vaxxed*? We don't for *waxed* or *vexed* or *fixed*, or *any other* word ending in -x – except, interestingly, another newly coined, highly politicized word, [*doxxed*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dox).

The subjective experience of living in 2021 reveals the popular preference for *vaxxed* over *vaxed* – see the headlines above, social media, etc. [Google Trends shows similarly](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=vaxed,vaxxed).

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vaxed%2Cvaxxed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVAXED%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVaxxed%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cvaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVaxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVAXED%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVaxxed%3B%2Cc00) starts to complicate and flesh out tale. *Vaxed*, the spelling of choice in the 1918 pandemic, predominates usage until 2016, when *Vaxxed*, capitalized, takes over. Interestingly, lower-case *vaxxed* makes a single appearance in Google's 1800-2019 English corpus.

The capitalized *Vaxxed* makes reference to 2016 pseudoscience documentary *Vaxxed*, about the imagined ties between vaccines and autism – the early core of the anti-vac movement.

Five years later, a world dependent on vaccines is talking about the doses in a flurry, and has appropriated the conspiracist orthography: *vaxxed*.

So what's going on? Are there non-anti-vax origins to the spelling? Is there a linguistic rationale for the double *x*? Given the double *x*'s other appearance in recent and charged *doxxed*, are we observing a change in orthographical norms (perhaps toward duplicate letters, broadly, or a changed pronunciation/conceptualization of *x*) or is there simply a provocative appearance to *xx*, encouraging its use in provocative words?

---

*Particularly the portion of the world with [patent-protected exclusive access](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/21/world/vaccine-patents-us-eu.html) to vaccines.

Comment: No source or rule, but my brain hears “vaxed” like “baked” and “vaxxed” like “backed”. But it also hears “doxed” like “boxed”, so maybe that’s not why.

Comment: The only source I looked at *disagrees* with me! I'd rather write ***nixxed*** (quirky past tense verb meaning "reduced to nothing, cancelled, nullified"). But the full OED only has ***nixed***.

Comment: @StephenS I agree! _Vaxxed_ made sense to me until I read _waxed_ somewhere yesterday, and thought, "well, we don't pronounce it way-xed – what's going on?"

Comment: Conspiracies and politics aside, I'm wondering if it's a matter of how we understand _x_. The pattern for short vowels, generally, is to double up before _-ed_, but we don't do that with x. Is that because we recognize (or _recognized_) _x_ as a single letter representing two sounds, and so it didn't need to be duplicated before -e? And now that's changing?

Comment: Double xx could be imitating **double cc** in the original *vacc*. Just to complicate it, vacc-inated didn't originally mean inoculated, but cow-pox inoculated. Vaca=cow in Spanish. Vache=cow in French.

Comment: Hasn't 'Vaxed' been genericised to 'vaxed', like 'hoovered'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was surprised to see that it was ever capitalized. Was Vaxed originally trademarked?

Comment: I imagine DEC trademarked it. “VAX is a CISC instruction set architecture and line of superminicomputers and workstations developed by the Digital Equipment Corporation in the mid-1970s. The VAX-11/780, introduced October 25, 1977, was the first of a range of popular and influential computers implementing the VAX ISA.” Wikipedia

Comment: @Xanne This seems unrelated?

Comment: [Vax](https://www.vax.co.uk/) is a British vacuum cleaner brand.  I've never heard of it being genericized to a verb, the way that the Hoover brand has been, but I'm not a BrE speaker. I'm not sure whether @EdwinAshworth was making a joke or referring to an actual BrE verb "to vax" meaning "to use a vacuum cleaner."

Comment: Oh oh so is this a story of "vaxed" already having a separate meaning?

Comment: There are lots of other fairly recent formations that use non-standard consonant doubling, such as "revved" as in engine. Presumably because it seems normal to double a consonant when forming a past participle even if double X or double V is abnormal. It might be interesting looking at the popularity of "vax" as a verb or noun; is "vaxxed" from an existing verb or noun "vax", or is it just a shortening of "vaccinated"?

Comment: I'm following this question because I wondered **the exact same thing** when I saw on Stephen Colbert last night his punny segment titled "The Vax-Scene" and then not an hour later saw on Seth Meyers the word "vaxxed," and I was all, "Why *two* Xs?!" Then I remembered "anti-vaxxer" (the root of "vaxxed") has two Xs, surmising either someone thought not adding the extra X would make the A long or it's just out of similarity to the two Cs in "vaccine," which I can easily see why it wasn't instead coined as "anti-vaccer," because phonetically, it's not readily apparent what that would mean.

Comment: So why the need to inject your theories on autism and vaccines?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Surely the most consistent shortened term for someone opposed to vaccination would be "anti-vaccser" which would avoid all this difficulty with 'x' completely. Does 'anti-vaxer' have something to do with the American spelling of 'sox' rather than 'socks'?

Comment: @BoldBen - "Anti-vaccser," because of the s, is inconsistent with the spelling "vaccine." Inconsistent is inconsistent, so a choice between "anti-vaccser" and "anti-vaxxer" is a choice between two inconsistencies, leaving neither with more merit than the other and making it entirely a matter of opinion. "Anti-vaxxer" has nothing to do with "sox," which, by the way, isn't the American spelling as the American spelling is "socks." MLB teams use the spelling "Sox" simply because they they couldn't register "White Socks" and "Red Socks," respectively, as trademarks as both are common items.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee I've used it and heard it used. It can't be claimed to be idiomatic, though: 100 Google hits for "vaxed the carpet", 1 for "vaxed the hall'. You have to be careful with trademarks though; Biro sued someone trying to genericise their name.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's partly because we're replacing the double c, so it seems natural to replace them with double x's. This would apply to doxxed (short for doccuments) also.

Fax>faxed, max>maxed, etc. are all from single x's.

I suspect meme culture also has something to do with it. Common usage of vaxxed was all over the internet before official sources got involved.

Comment: _doxxed (short for doccuments)_ but documents has only one 'c'...